# Get Area and SubArea name by reverse geocoding in ng-Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I am new to angularJS, I use the ngAutocomplete to get the locations from google service. It gives me the latitude and longitude whenever I select a location.

Now, I want to get the area and location name from selected latitude and longitude by reverse geocoding service.

I want to use the googple javascript API in ngAutocomplete module, so if user selects a location then It will return the area and location name too.

Thnanks

Comment: Google has an api for reverse geocoding , you're going to have to read it and start to write out some code and get as far as you can then come bak with a question

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show us a sample of your code and try to clarify your question. I encourage you to take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and consult the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) for guidance on asking good questions on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are may be asking about Reverse Geocoding to get the detail information of location.
You can get the enough information about the Reverse Geocoding from

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you, I will implement this into ngAutocomplete.